# Add Additional Label to DropDown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the below `dropdown` list and I would like to add the "`cost`" of the membership that is stored in my database. I would also like it formatted as currency when displayed in the `dropdown` list. Is there a way to do this?

The Data column is SignupFee

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customer.MemberShipTypeID, new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes, "Id", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: How are you populating `Model.MembershipTypes` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes, "Id", "Name")
```

Do:

```
Model.MembershipTypes.Select(m => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = m.Id.ToString(),
    Text = String.Format("{0} {1:C}", m.Name, m.Cost)
});
```

All `DropDownListFor` needs is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, by using LINQ's `Select`, you can customize exactly how the `Text` value is set.

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you!